# How to sort massive map by one value property?

Tags: c++, sorting, boost, dictionary

I have a `map<std::string, myStruct>` I wonder how to sort items in map by int property that is in `myStruct.order` and if 2 or more of `myStruct` orders are same throw list of keys (strings) that make map unsortable by that field of myStruct? Is there any fancy way of doing in in C++03 (may be with boost)?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/ this doesn't help?

Comment: Turn the map around and make it a `map<myStruct, std::string>`, and you get this behaviour for free (provided you equip your class with a comparison operator).

Answer (score 1):

boost has a complete (and complex) functionality in [MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html), but if I understand your requirements, it's overkill in this case. A fairly easy way could be to build a list of pointers to myStruct and sort. Then you can easily check for duplicate keys (these became adjacents).

sort should use a functor of type `less<const myStruct*>`, i.e.

```
bool compare_orders(const myStruct* a, const myStruct* b) { return a->order < b->order; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, using `std::map` - the `first` in the `pair` is used for comparing (it's called *key*). In your case, the`std::string` is the *key*.

You can use `std::set< std::pair< std::string, MyStruct > >` and then implement `operator<` for two `std::pair< std::string, MyStruct >`-s.

Or, you can change the `std::map`'s definition, if it's possible/allowed/suitable/etc. It really depends on what you're trying to do and what you're allowed to do.

Or some other container (that keeps the order of elements, as inserted - like `std::list`, `std::vector`, etc.), and then using `std::sort` or container's `sort` method, if exists.

Answer (score 0):

What meaning is there in "sorting" a map? Sure, the map may be internally organized as a BST or something to make access faster, but conceptionally the elements of the map are in no particular order.

Other than that, you CAN supply an ordering method for the keys (because even if you do organize the map in a particular way, it is by the order of the keys, not by that of the values), but not for the values with the third template argument for map.

Comment: This is not correct, a std::map is *by definition* a sorted data structure, even conceptually. An example of a conceptually unsorted map is std::unordered_map.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers that it's not clear why you need to sort the map. But you can use a *bidirectional map* to let you view both myStruct and string as keys.

There's one in boost:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html

There's an example here

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/examples/simple_bimap.html